# Measuring Li-ion battery manage to get a number in mAh

Tags: batteries, measurement, test

How can a circuit functioning to measure Li-ion or else type battery manage to get its mAh capacity, how is this circuit's method ?

**EDIT**

[image]

Known it from a reviewer fed into an e-commerce site I forget (likely China's)

Comment: what is your understanding about what Ah (amp-hours) means?

Comment: mAh = integration of mA X time during discharge. Eg if a battery discharged at 1200 mA for 3 hours the capacity is 1200x 3 = 3600 mAh. If the discharge  rate varies then summing the individual parts is required. Eg if you measure mA once per second, then summing the results gives mA seconds. Dividing the sum by 3600 gives mAh ( as 3600 seconds per hour).

Comment: Given the specific way in which lithium-ion batteries tend to fail... I'm not sure "ultrafire" was the best choice of name for that brand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short NIST article describes the history and 2019 redefinition of the SI unit relationships between Ampere and Coulomb:

https://www.nist.gov/si-redefinition/ampere-introduction

> In November 2018, however, the redefinition of the ampere ― along with three other SI base units: the kilogram (mass), kelvin (temperature) and mole (amount of substance) ― was approved. Starting on May 20, 2019, the ampere is based on a fundamental physical constant: the elementary charge (e), which is the amount of electric charge in a single electron (negative) or proton (positive).

> The ampere is a measure of the amount of electric charge in motion per unit time ― that is, electric current. But the quantity of electric charge by itself, whether in motion or not, is expressed by another SI unit, the coulomb (C). One coulomb is equal to about 6.241E+18 electric charges (e). One ampere is the current in which one coulomb of charge travels across a given point in 1 second.

The battery stores some of its internal electric charge in a high energy state in the chemical potential. The State of Charge (SoC) refers to how much of these energetic Coulombs are available to develop electrical power and therefore perform electrical work. If one could accurately measure SoC it would be like a fuel gauge. But due to the nature of chemical energy storage the fuel gauge is always some sort of estimate of the SoC in a particular battery even if the SoC is measured using special devices known as Coulomb Counters.

This five page article describes basic methods to infer SoC using voltage sampling with knowledge of discharge curves and/or to use coulomb counter devices which integrate current over time to count coulombs during charge or discharge of a battery:

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical-articles/P356_EN-SOC.pdf

Type this into Google search bar "1 ampere-hour in coulombs". The result given: 1 = 3,600. Mathematically the current I = dq/dt and the amount of charge q associated with the process is the integral of the differential equation dq = Idt.

The coulomb counter is an effort to solve the integral in a measurement device and to infer something about the SoC based on the measurement which still assumes something about the chemistry, initial conditions, and perhaps also the operating history of the particular battery.

This article describes how a coulomb counter in a battery management system can "get confused" about SoC:

https://www.digikey.com/en/blog/count-those-coulombs-for-lithium-battery-fitness

The author infers that the coulomb counter in his electronic device may lose track of the correct SoC and then needs to re-learn some information via proper calibration procedure (deep discharge and full recharge).

Comment: Also from C=Q/Vavg you can infer any battery has an equivalent capacitance directly from cell voltage range (10 to 15%) and Ah.  Where the “C charge rating” is a inversely related to ESR

Comment: A few years ago I would read published performance data for small scale electric cars 1/10, 1/16, etc. The authors would "dyno" the battery-motor combination and publish the exponential decay curve for acceleration up to 60 mph with speed as rising exponential. These authors would state that some motors "heat up" and "fade" sooner than other motors in a 5-7 minute racing event. However I concluded that a less effective and/or efficient battery-motor combination would deplete the battery sooner. The output voltage would drop and internal resistance go up causing shaft power fade in PMDC motor.

Comment: Both are possible but 6000'K arc temperatures and I^2R losses that saturate L and torque are more pronounced than the linear loss in Q and could increase the current drain faster. Core losses above 100'C are significant unless CRGOS transformer steel was used

Comment: Heat fade is certainly a factor, however, in a racing event the I^2R losses happen at low speeds, high current, and high torque to accelerate out of low speed turns up to high speeds in straight sections. Integrating dQ = Idt I estimated that most of the high energy Q in the battery is used up overcoming mechanical friction and via sharp bursts of aggressive acceleration to increase kinetic energy of the car and its driveline. Motor with high rotor inertia saps Q so rotor optimization matters. Brushless motors eliminate brush losses dissipate heat better with coils on the stator (heat sink).

Comment: I have found those electric model motors optimized for power/mass ratio are also water cooled.

Comment: I noticed that a motor that makes more raw shaft power on the dyno might also have longer spin up time meaning more shaft intertia Jm than a motor with similar input current, torque, rpm speed, but spins up in less time. This means less Q as the area under the curve for integral of Idt. The motors with more Jm and spin up time were the ones that would be reported as fading sooner due to "heat" in the motor coils. High current draw increases coil temperature which increase motor resistance Rm and also internal battery resistance Rs. Power fade due to decrease of battery voltage increase Rs, Rm.

Comment: Motor DCR needs to be much higher than battery ESR to improve efficiency. Although MPT occurs when matched efficiency is only 50%

Comment: Racing 1/10 scale electric vehicles is interesting to understand battery performance, electrical, and mechanical system optimization for the goal of winning a race. These events are time limited due to the limits of battery capacity. This 22 page paper https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-071j-introduction-to-electronics-signals-and-measurement-spring-2006/lecture-notes/03_kirchhoff1.pdf shows non-ideal voltage source line in Figure 18(b) on nominal page 17.  Intercepts are Vs/Rs and Vs where Vs goes down Rs goes up as battery is depleted causes power fade.

Answer (score 0):

You can't know capacity unless you measure a charge or discharge cycle and measure the current and voltage of the cell. It's also good to know the chemistry of the cell.

One way is to fully charge the cell and then discharge it and measure how much power it takes to discharge the cell to it's low point

If you know the chemistry you may be able to get by with just voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Rated capacity is given for slow constant current in 20H defined as 1C. But often users expect the same capacity for 20C or a 1h CC discharge. Peukert’s Law defines a way to estimate the loss of capacity but the data-sheet guaranteed new specs are best bet. Avoiding full discharge extends the life cycle charges. In many cases using 90% to 50% extends cycles by about 10x according to Batteryuniverity.com

Answer (score 0):

Earlier answers appear to be answering the question of "how much capacity would a fully-charged battery have?".

The image you've added to your question makes it look like, instead, your question is "how much capacity is left in this particular battery at this particular time?".

To answer that, you'll need to know the battery's discharge curve for the particular current being drawn from it.  (This can be plotted by fully charging it, then discharging it at the current level in question, as @voltage-spike said.  But you have to do that in preparation.)  With that plot, you can measure the voltage on the battery under the load, match it to a point on the discharge curve, and look at how much time is left before the battery's voltage will drop below your particular load's minimum usable voltage.

Then you multiply those values together (if the units are milliamps and hours), to get the mAh remaining.

The measurement device that's in the photo you posted is likely getting its mAh number from some rules of thumb for the minimum usable voltages of various devices, and the discharge curves at various load levels.  That is, it's probably not exact, though it's probably relatively close.